# How to update many values in mongodb by the list of IDs?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I use pymongo to work with mongodb. The problem is: I need to update a lot of collection entries in mongodb by the list of ids.

There is a collection `abcd` with following structure:

```
{'id': 'someid1', 'order': 0}
{'id': 'someid2', 'order': 0}
...
{'id': 'someidN', 'order': 0}
```

I need to change `order` fields with the values collected in dict `mapping`.

```
mapping = {'someid1': 5, 'someid2': 7, ..., 'someidN': 50}
```

The most obvious way (may be not correct since it took a lot of time and I interrupted the process) is:

```
for key, value in mapping.items():
    db.abcd.update_one({'id': key}, {'order': {'$set': value}})
```

But as I see, it is very time-consuming. Is there any smart way to set values by the list of values? Something like that (following code is stupid and does not work as I expected):

```
db.abcd.update_many({'id': list(mapping.keys())}, {'order': {'$set': list(mapping.values())})
```

I have read mongodb docs, but found only examples with "condition" (e.g. change field with the same value if condition is True). I guess that there is an efficient way to "map" values to the multiple ids at once. I am new to mongodb (and pymongo as well), so question is probably quite silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any smart way to set values by the list of values?

Using the standard update operators, unfortunately not. Mongodb works by needing a filter for the update, so anything like you are attempting is not doable in a single `update_many()`.

Make sure [you have an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db-collection-createindex) on the `id` field in your example. The `_id` field is always indexed (and always unique) you could consider using that instead.

With that said your simple operation shouldn't be too slow, unless you have a slow machine / network or a very large data set. (noting though that your code shouldn't have worked - your `$set` operator was in the wrong place)

One option to speed things up is to use [bulk write operations](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations). The code below shows how this can be done.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
import pprint

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Test Data setup

for i in range(3):
    db.abcd.insert_one({'id': f'someid{i}', 'order': 0})

mapping = {'someid1': 5, 'someid2': 7}

updates = []

for key, value in mapping.items():
    updates.append(UpdateOne({'id': key}, {'$set': {'order': value}}))

# print the results

db.abcd.bulk_write(updates)

pprint.pprint(list(db.abcd.find({}, {'_id': 0})))
```

returns:

```
[{'id': 'someid0', 'order': 0},
 {'id': 'someid1', 'order': 5},
 {'id': 'someid2', 'order': 7}]
```